# Does CLGeocoder send AppleID, or PhoneID, etc?

Tags: ios, geolocation, geocode, clgeocoder

I am using Apple's `CLGeocoder` to do geocoding. I am mostly calling `– reverseGeocodeLocation:`.

The docs state that the old geocoder used Google, and they have a TOS that I can read. I can't find one for Apple.

Experimentally has any one looked at the packets coming to and from a CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: call to figure out what information Apple is getting?

I need to know for privacy reasons. It would seem that the service could be anonymous (except for IP tracking, etc), but Apple could also send along the phone's serial number, etc.